# Issues ascending and descending

Tags: php, ajax

I am using ajax with php to sort and display my DB. However I can not switch between asc and desc. It only works for ASC, although I don't know why. $isAsc is staying at 1 no matter how many times I press the button. (I am using PHP 7.1)
//AJAX

```
$('#sort_by_name').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php?order=<?php echo isset($_GET['order'])?!$_GET['order']:1; ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        asynch: false,
        data: {
            "sort_by_name":1
        },
        success: function(d){                
            $('#movie_container').html(d);
        }
    });
});
```

//PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['sort_by_name'])) {
$isAsc = isset($_GET['order']) ? (bool) $_GET['order'] : 1;
if ($isAsc) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, movie_name, movie_year, movie_rating, movie_description, movie_imdb, movie_image, movie_my_rating FROM movies ORDER BY movie_name ASC";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            include 'show_movie_and_ribbon.php';
        }
    }
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT id, movie_name, movie_year, movie_rating, movie_description, movie_imdb, movie_image, movie_my_rating FROM movies ORDER BY movie_name DESC";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            include 'show_movie_and_ribbon.php';
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: typo on that line ? url: "data.php?order=<?php echo isset($_GET['order']) **?!** $_GET['order']:1; ?>",

Comment: tried it, but variable $isAsc is still not changing between 0 and 1 -> stays only 1. So I guess it is this line "url: "data.php?order=<?php echo isset($_GET['order'])?!$_GET['order']:1; ?>", because whenever I access the file directly and change the order manually it works

Comment: Any reason why you are using the $_GET variable to store the ordering? I don't think that gets updated when you make the ajax call, that might be the problem.

Comment: I was looking for a solution and found one answer on this website by someone who used the exact code with $_GET. That is the reason I am using it. I don't know which one will work with ajax. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: your condition seems a bit weird with ?! in it

Comment: don't know exatcly how you need things done, but does this help ? [test code](https://pastebin.com/mmQ7eAiW) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to get url parameters:

Insert the order parameter into data.

Check this code:

### Javascript

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;


        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }


    $('#sort_by_name').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: 'POST',
            asynch: false,
            data: {
                "sort_by_name":1,
                 "order":getUrlParameter('order')?:1
            },
            success: function(d){                
                $('#movie_container').html(d);
            }
        });
    });
```

### PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['sort_by_name'])) {
$isAsc = isset($_POST['order']) ? $_POST['order'] : 1;
if ($isAsc) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, movie_name, movie_year, movie_rating, movie_description, movie_imdb, movie_image, movie_my_rating FROM movies ORDER BY movie_name ASC";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            include 'show_movie_and_ribbon.php';
        }
    }
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT id, movie_name, movie_year, movie_rating, movie_description, movie_imdb, movie_image, movie_my_rating FROM movies ORDER BY movie_name DESC";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            include 'show_movie_and_ribbon.php';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tried the code, but now nothing is displayed.
Says: that order is not declared and var getUrlParameter is unused

Comment: I change the function call, try it now.

Comment: thank you for still trying to help me, but still not working. Nothing is showed nor any error message.

Comment: The variable $isAsc is not getting set, because I put alert in both if and else and neither of them is executed.

Comment: Did you take my php code? print something if you insert into `sort_by_name` and print post array.

Comment: take a look in network tab, what you get in php script response?

Comment: Yes, I took all your code. Now I have:

if (isset($_POST['sort_by_name'])) {
    print_r($_POST);

the response is 200 OK
and under the Response tab I am getting my movies.php

I took enough of your time, don't worry, just going to do it with 2 different buttons. Thank you again!